# How to pass series of variables in function as array or regardless of their order?

Tags: php

I am sorry, that sounds like a noob question. I am trying to do this, maybe my question is not clear.

I want to be able to pass something like this:

```
make_thumbnail( array( 'width' => 60, 'height' => 40', 'title' => 'my image' ) );
```

Now the above line calls the function which already produces the thumbnails I have that no problem, but I want flexibility here. I mean my function has variables ordered like this:

```
function make_thumbnail($title,$width,$height) {

the code..

echo ...

}
```

Now you get what I want to do? I want to be able to pass the variables in any order.. they do not have to come in same order title, width, height..  i want to be able to specify the order when I call the function in template as I put in very first line.

I tried to make my question as clear as I can, but really could not find anything about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sort of thing?

```
function make_thumbnail($myarray) {
$sometitle = $myarray["title"]
$somewidth = $myarray["width"]
$someheight = $myarray["height"]
}
```

Comment: Simpler than I thought ? ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Why not have the array as the function argument?  e.g.

```
function make_thumbnail($argsArray) {
  echo $argsArray['width'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create variables within your function for each parameter

```
function make_thumbnail($argsArray) {  
  $width = $argsArray['width'];  
  $height = $argsArray['height'];  
  $title = $argsArray['title'];  

  // ...plug the rest of your original function here  
}
```

Then your function will behave exactly the same, except you can pass in an array.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is a description of the Reflection syntax of PHP:

```
function callWithNamedParams( $funcName, array $args = null )
{
    if( is_null( $args ) ) return $funcName();
    $f = new ReflectionFunction($funcName);
    $input = array();
    foreach( $f->getParameters() as $param )
    {
        array_push( $input, @$args[ $param->getName() ] );
    }
    return call_user_func_array( $funcName, $input );
}
```

Use:

```
function myFunc( $foo, $bar )
{
    echo "foo = $foo;  Bar = $bar";
}

callWithNamedParams( "myFunc", array( "bar"=>1, "foo"=>2 ) );
```

You should get `foo = 2;  Bar = 1` as an output.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define your logic to take any parameter as the one you want it to be. Array is the best thing you can use. But changing the parameters changes the signatures.
you are kinda implementing polymorphism but in a wrong way..